# MariaDB using 1000+ parameters with EXPLAIN

Tags: mariadb, mysqli

Can you confirm if this is a bug... I cannot work out if it's MariaDB (10.3.34 or 10.7.3), PHP (mysqlnd), or a mistake I've made:

```php
<?php

  $db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

  // $db->query('SET in_predicate_conversion_threshold=2000;');

  $count = 1000;

  $params = implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, '?'));
  $types = str_repeat('i', $count);
  $values = array_fill(0, $count, 3);

  $statement = $db->prepare('EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id IN (' . $params . ')');
  $statement->bind_param($types, ...$values);
  $statement->execute();

  $result = $statement->get_result();

  var_dump($db->error);
  var_dump($statement->error);
  var_dump($statement->errno);
  var_dump($result);

?>
```

This hangs when it gets to `$statement->execute()`, and does not show any error message.

If you remove `EXPLAIN` from the SQL (to make a normal `SELECT` query), the `$statement->get_result()` fails (returns false or exception, depending on `mysqli_report`), and you get the error message "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

---

The 1,000 parameter limit within `IN()` seems to be related to `in_predicate_conversion_threshold`; and you can have multiple `IN()` operators with 999 parameters each.

Comment: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" refers to the calls before your failing case and/or multi-statement executes and/or stored procs.

Comment: Use the "general log" to see what the constructed query looks like.